# How to divide 12V/15A buck converter output into two outputs with the same specs?

Tags: current, buck, converter, output

I am currently working on a project to build a mini-atx pc for a rover. Heres a simple schematic of it :

[image]

The picoPSU Atx connector takes in 12V DC with a max of 15A peak and the zotac gpu 12V DC with a max of around 10A peak. I want to connect these two to my battery via a buck converter but I cannot find one that supports multiple outputs and high current. So I figured I would just divide the output but I do not know how that could be done. Anyone has an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Your buck converter will just collapse if both loads require the peak current at the same time. You can try to mitigate this to a degree with large capacitors, but additional energy will not come out of subspace.

Comment: That's not a schematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a strong enough buck converter (25A) you can just power both devices in parallel (just connect two wires to each output terminal).  With that battery you should get about 40 minutes of run time, less if you're running motors etc.

Actually less time that that, a buck converter is going to want more than 12V (maybe 13V) to operate correctly so you can only discharge down to (say) 3.25V per cell before your computer stops. You may want to use a 5 cell battery instead.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was a solution but I thought it to be unreliable and dangerous. Thanks!

Comment: Most PC powersupplies connect all the 12V outputs internally

Comment: How would you go about calculating worst case battery life and maybe like an average value? Lets say the battery only powers the pc

Comment: Also another question I had, if I splice the three 12V gpu wires together and the three ground gpu wires together to connect to my buck converter would that be safe?

Comment: yes, there are three wires to carry more current without being too fat to bend easily,  this sort of thing is normal inside PCs but illegal in house wiring.  I guess this is because PCs are less flammable than houses.